# Python - string split into columns by template

Tags: python, string

I have a string with spaces and I would like to insert commas `,` into specific positions based on a template that I define into a list.

For example:

1. Input

   ```
   String_in = "{080002092014Mark    21022017392 Ert02 stereo-Gaman09 39-934.4930start 23kg0093029   }"

   Template = [2,5,13,21,29,30,33,39,44,55,61,63,65,77]
   ```
2. Output

   ```
   String_out = "{0,800,02092014,Mark     ,2102201,3,92 ,Ert02 ,stereo-Gaman09 ,39-934.4930,start ,23,kg,0093029   ,}
   ```

Code Tried:

```
def my_f(string, template, comma):
    for i in template:
        print(string[:i] + comma + string[i:])
my_f("asd asdget t45 4", {1,3,7}, ",")
```

Output:

```
a,sd asdget t45 4
asd, asdget t45 4
asd asd,get t45 4
```

There should only be 1 line with all the commas, not 3 lines.

Comment: What did you try that didn't work?

Comment: You have an inconsistencies in your expected output. For `2` you have a comma in the second index of the string (zero-based), but for `5` you have a comma in the sixth index (zero-based). For `13` you have a comma in the 15th index (again, zero-based).

Comment: I think you should look at the input string before adding the commas. Otherwise every index will be shifted by the number of commas before it.

Comment: @DeepSpace It looks like he means "position", so just counting, not "index". So position would be pos=index+1 or index=pos-1. My guess.

Comment: @fedepad This method still produces inconsistencies when looking at the expected output.

Comment: Yes, I know...plus @HeshamAttia has a very good observation...

Comment: Dear all, just to simplify: I have a string, a template which indicates "multiple positions in the string", and I would like to insert a comma into these positions. Thank you for your help

Comment: The text in the output doesn't match the input and is leading to confusion. Specifically this part `21022017392` which was converted to `,2102201,3,92`. Notice the missing 7.

Comment: to over simplify:   string= "abc 123 d", template=[2,4,7] , output: string1="ab,c ,123, d"  Thank you

Comment: Please update your question, and also provide what you tried that didn't work.

Comment: Hi, updated as following: 

def my_f(string, template, comma):

    for i in template:

        print(string[:i] + comma + string[i:])

my_f("asd asdget t45 4", {1,3,7}, ",")

Result: 
>>>a,sd asdget t45 4

>>>asd, asdget t45 4

>>>asd asd,get t45 4    

It gives me 3 lines - I just need 1 :-(

Comment: Thanks for posting your code, could you please edit the original question above with this code?

Comment: Ok, done. Thank you

Comment: You know you should print only once if you want just one line, so you should "save" somehow the previous states and act on them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do something like:

```
def split_by_template(s, template, sep=","):
  output_pieces = []
  prev_pos = 0
  for i in template + [len(s)]:
    output_pieces += [s[prev_pos:i]]
    prev_pos = i
  return sep.join(output_pieces)
```

---

Or a more concise solution:

```
def split_by_template(s, template, sep=","):
  return sep.join(s[a:b] for a, b in zip([0] + template, template + [len(s)]))
```

This basically zips every template position with the previous one, so a template like `[1, 2, 5]`, would produce pairs of `[(0, 1), (1, 2), (2, 5), (5, len(str)]`. Note that we added an extra [0] and [len(str) at the beginning and the end, so the first and last pieces are correct.

Then cut the relevant pieces of the string, and join them by comma.

Comment: Are you sure your second solution runs ok? Using `def split_by_template(stringa, template, comma):
  comma.join(stringa[a:b] for a, b in zip([0] + template, template))

print(split_by_template("asd asdget t45 4", [1,3,7], ","))` prints `None`. Am I missing something?

Comment: I like the one-liner.  :) Anyway, there is a bug in the solution. You are missing the last portion. The fix is easy.

Comment: Oh yes, just add the `return` in the one-liner and fix as the last part of the string is not printed for both proposed solutions.

Comment: `+ [len(s)]` after the second `template`. Use something like `s` instead of `str` as `str` would mask the built-in function name. And the `return`, of course. And rename the function to show what it really does. :)

Comment: Thanks guys, fixed.

Comment: @hesham Still missing the last portion. Please, the one-liner is nicer. Fix it. And use `sep` instead of `comma` and give it the default value.

Comment: To make it more understandable, the `templates` should be renamed to `positions`, and the function to something like `separate_at_positions`. ;) I also suggest to use `lst` as generic name for a list variable in such simple cases. Also `lst.append(x)` is probably more readable than `lst += [x]`.

Comment: Agreed, but this is code is just to demonstrate an idea, and to answer the OPs question, rather than being used as a generic library method. I think it's currently pretty understandable given the original question and the examples.

Answer (score 0):

You can use string slicing to get the portions of the string and make a list of the portions. Then use
','.join(lst) to get the result.

Loop through the template values, remember the previous (say pos1 and pos2). The String_in[pos1:pos2] gets the portion. The last portion will be String_in[pos1:]. The pos1 will be initialized to zero, the pos2 will be the loop variable -- assigned to pos1 at the end of the loop.

```
lst = []
pos1 = 0
for pos2 in Template:
    lst.append(String_in[pos1:pos2])
    pos1 = pos2
lst.append(String_in[pos1:])
String_out = ','.join(lst)
```

Something like that, but not tested -- not being at the computer with Python.

Comment: String_in, String_out, and Template don't seem to follow python's naming conventions. Also I think pos and prev_pos would be more readable since they are more indicative of the variables usage, rather than pos1 and pos2.

Comment: @HeshamAttia You are right. But they are the names from the question. Trade-offs are everywhere. On the other hand `pos1` is the first position for the slice indexing, and `pos2` is the second position. From the point of view of slicing the `s[prev_pos:i]` is less readable, in my opinion. ;)